# Причинять добро

Tags: стилистика, лексика

Интересно, почему в русском языке *причинять* можно только нечто отрицательное?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Строгого ограничения нет, можно говорить и просто о "причиненных последствиях" и даже "причиненном добре", хотя обычно действительно подразумевается что-то отрицательное. Я думаю, причина здесь в том, что слово стало прочно ассоциироваться с языком юристов, где используется исключительно в подобных "негативных" контекстах.

Я хотел посмотреть, когда, собственно, значение стало связывать исключительно с негативными последствиями, но нацкорпус не даёт исчерпывающей информации. Во всяком случае в XVIII веке еще встречались обороты типа "причинить всевозможное исправление в государственной экономии". [Н. И. Новиков. О торговле вообще (1783)], явно не несущие "негатива", но общая тенденция уже налицо.